# Why no roundoff error when dividing by h in this approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, derivatives

Why the approximation $f'(x) = ( f(x+h) - f(x-h) ) / 2h$ produces no roundoff error if $h = 2^{-k}$, where $k$ is any integer.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be referring to the machine roundoff error inherent in the way computers represent floating point numbers as binary.  When $h = 2^{-k}$, this is an exact representation of $h$ in a machine, so there is no inherent roundoff.

Comment: I also draw your attention to Sec. 5.7 of Numerical Recipes in C (2nd Ed.) for further discussion of roundoff error in computing derivatives.  http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I am quite new to error analysis. And thanks for your recommendation to the book.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you found this useful, please remember to accept the solution by clicking the checkmark.